# Obtain the highest codes repeating and non-repeating from the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 39 | 20180527 |
| 1 | 17 | 20180223 |
| 1 | 17 | 20180223 |
| 1 | 17 | 20180223 |
| 1 | 30 | 20120612 |
| 1 | 14 | 20120214 |
| 2 | 40 | 20210605 |
| 2 | 32 | 20210412 |
| 2 | 25 | 20210315 |
| 3 | 39 | 20170504 |
| 3 | 17 | 20170205 |
| 3 | 40 | 20150506 |

As you can see, the highest codes have the highest date. I want to extract those codes and dates.
Some of them are repeating. For instance, in id 1, the highest codes are 39 and 30, I want to gain those codes and the date associated with them.
One thing to notice here is that there is one year gap between the values of the highest code dates.
The output from the above dataset should be:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 39 | 20180527 |
| 1 | 30 | 20120612 |
| 2 | 40 | 20210605 |
| 3 | 39 | 20170504 |
| 3 | 40 | 20150506 |

I tried to use the following code, but it gives me only the highest value and does not consider the duplicate values.

```
latest_dates = column_selection.groupby("id").max() # group the data by id and get the max date for each group

latest_dates = latest_dates.reset_index() # reset the index

latest_dates # print the latest date for each ID with the new index
```

This is the output I get using the above code:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 39 | 20180527 |
| 2 | 40 | 20210605 |
| 3 | 39 | 20170504 |

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Why does `id` 2 have only one value, where `id` 1 and 3 have two?

Comment: Hi Nick, I have already mentioned this in the question. Since the id has more than 1-year gap between them, I want to get the highest code value. As you can see, id 1 has two codes that have more than 1-year gap (39 and 30). While id 2 has only 1 highest code value, and there is no 1-year gap between the codes (40). Similar for id 3.

Comment: So, if there were three highest values for `id` 1 which were all more than a year apart from each other, you would want all three of them?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! There can be multiple highest values (1-year apart), I want to get them all.

Comment: @SukrutShishupal taken the assumption that if a `year` diff is less than one you want the higher value of the two code values?

Comment: @Umar.H yes, that's correct. If the difference is less than one year, get the highest value amongst the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.nlargest(2)` and `.loc` to filter your index values.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['id'])['code'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]

    id  code      date
0    1    39  20180527
4    1    30  20120612
6    2    40  20210605
7    2    32  20210412
11   3    40  20150506
9    3    39  20170504
```

---

Another method would be to use `.sort_values` and `.cumcount` with a boolean filter.

```
 df.loc[df.sort_values('code',ascending=False).groupby('id').cumcount().le(1)]



    id  code      date
0    1    39  20180527
4    1    30  20120612
6    2    40  20210605
7    2    32  20210412
9    3    39  20170504
11   3    40  20150506
```

---

### Edit - handling year diffs.

After you've got your dataframe, we can turn the `date` field into a proper date and apply a `diff` at an `id` level after sorting the `date` field

you can then create a secondary key to de-dupe your values that less than a years difference between them.

```
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

s = df.loc[df.groupby(['id'])['code'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]


con = (s.sort_values(['id','date']
           ).groupby('id')['date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'Y')).fillna(1)


s['grp'] = s.groupby(['id', con.lt(1)]).cumcount()

out = s.sort_values(['id', 'code']).drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'grp'],keep='last').drop('grp',axis=1)


    id  code       date
4    1    30 2012-06-12
0    1    39 2018-05-27
6    2    40 2021-06-05
9    3    39 2017-05-04
11   3    40 2015-05-06
```

---

diving a little deeper, we need two conditions to filter by.

1. any values that have `less` than a `year` delta between them.
2. of those values take the higher of the two.

Comment: This doesn't match OPs desired output. See my comment to the question and the reply

Comment: @Nick - thanks. Simple(ish) enough - but could probably be less verbose on my side.

Comment: @Nick much prefer to tackle these more fun analytical queries in pure SQL these days, but pandas (and Polars) is pretty fun

Comment: Yeah, this would be trivial in most SQL languages, but it's definitely interesting to try and figure out how to solve things using pandas instead.

Comment: Hi @Umar.H, I ran the above code, but it is still giving only the highest value for each id. For instance, id 1 should give 2 codes, but I am getting only one value.

Comment: @SukrutShishupal does your data match the provided input? if i re-run it I get the expected output.

Comment: Hi @Umar.H, I checked the dataset, and after making a few changes, it worked. Thank you so much!!

Comment: no worries mate @SukrutShishupal - just make a clear example of your basic input and output.